# jhipster om.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy warnings

Tags: oracle, jhipster, hikaricp

There seems to be some timeout issue going on here, the jhipster gui works fine and the database gets updated, but these warnings are cluttering up the logs.

```
Hibernate: insert into T_PERSISTENT_TOKEN (ip_address, token_date, token_value, user_login,   user_agent, series) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[WARN] com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy - Connection  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@700b4bdc (HikariPool-0) marked as broken because of SQLSTATE (08003), ErrorCode(17009).
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Statement
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClosedStatement.getMaxRows(OracleClosedStatement.java:3577) ~  [ojdbc-6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
```

whats the fix or how can they be suppressed?

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

- Make sure your Oracle has the latest patches applied.
- Upgrade your HikariCP to version 1.3.8.  Earlier versions had a bug in the isConnectionAlive() check that might return a closed connection from the pool.  If you don't want to upgrade, switch to using a SQL test query (`connectionTestQuery`) instead of the JDBC4 `isValid()` check (`jdbc4ConnectionTest=false`).
- Set the `maxLifetime` timeout to something less than the Oracle connection timeout, like 10 minutes instead of the default 30 minutes.